# USB_modeSwitch doesnt detect my huawei dongle as modem automatically

Tags: usb, modem, usb-modem, wwan

**Problem:**

I am using a Huawei dongle with me. 
On my current kernel version, I have installed usb_modeswitch.
As soon as I insert my Huawei dongle, it detects as mass storage instead of the modem.
**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
```

**Experiments**

1. made DisableSwitching=1 in usb_modeswitch.conf file. 
   this also doesn't work.
2. Issued `usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1506 -M "55534243123456780000000000000a11062000000000000100000000000000"`

At this time it will work and my device get detects as the modem and I an able to get wwan0 interface along with that.
But if I remove my dongle and insert it again, it again detects it as the storage device.

--> I want this to happen automatically, that no matter how many time I remove my dongle, it should always be get detected.

All these changes having below settings in kernel

```
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_WWAN=m
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_OPTION=m
```

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

After installing the latest version of usb_modeSwitch 2.5 its works fine.